# On running ng serve in angular, ./src/main.ts - Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled

Tags: angular, async-await, tsconfig

I am getting this error:

> ./src/main.ts - Error: Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true
> to enabled it)
>   * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
>   * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

I am new to angular please help

I tried looking on the internet but the solutions were for react and not angular.
I added `"experiments": { "topLevelAwait": true }` (outside compilerOptions) to the tsconfig.json file but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I would not want to enable experimental stuff for something I can avoid easily. Just make a single function where you put all your async stuff in and call that using `myFunction().then();` Perhaps you could show what you are trying to do in main.ts?